# What is the proper function for multi dimensional localized menu?

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n

What is the proper function to get multi dimensional localized menu in Drupal 7?
after searching, I found `i18n_menu_localize_tree()`, but I didn't get it as tree menu.
Should I use `i18n_menu_translated_tree()`, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

[menu_tree($menu_name)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree/7) Seems to do that. It runs the items through  [_menu_item_localize](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/_menu_item_localize/7).

It works if your menu is translatable. In my setup menu items were not assigned to language, but translated with 18n_menu from site default language.

This atleast gets translated menu. Localized menu might imply also to version where certain items are only shown with specific language active(in that case this answer migth not work).

Answer (score 1):

If you use the i18n_menu module for menu translation/localization, you can indeed use the `i18n_menu_localize_tree()` to retrieve the localized tree of an original given menu tree.

```
$tree = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu'); // Depending the requirements, you can use menu_tree or menu_tree_all_data

if(module_exists('i18n_menu')) {
    $tree= i18n_menu_localize_tree($tree);
}
```